# How to compute the "least occurring" elements in a Python list?

Tags: python, list, counter

Let's say I have a python list:

```
foo = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
```

How would I be able to extract the "least occurring" elements in the list?

Finding the majority elements is easier, doing the following:

```
print(max(foo, key=foo.count))
'A'
```

However, how could I efficiently find the least occurring? In the above example, it's `'B'`.

In terms of lists whereby all counts are the same, e.g. `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`, I think all items are "least occurring".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `max` with `min` and it will do your work.

Try this :

```
foo = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']

print(min(foo, key=foo.count))

>>>'B'
```

If you have multiple elements with least count same, you can use `collections.Counter` with dictionary.

Try this :

```
import collections

foo = ['A', 'B', 'C']

occurrences = collections.Counter(foo)

res =  [key for key in occurrences if all(occurrences[temp] >= occurrences[key] for temp in occurrences)] 

print(res)

>>>['A', 'B', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Counter` to obtain all counts in one iteration:

```
from collections import Counter

foo = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']

c = Counter(foo)
m = min(c.values())
mins = [x for x in foo if c[x] == m]
```